# Selecting data with multiple priorities and limited max entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to create a PHP script that selects data from MySQL table with multiple priorities?

Every MySQL row is an application for several "sports discipline" with sportsman score as the key for rating.

Sports columns holds the priority for each participient wish to participiate in exact sport. There are limited places for each sports.

That means  If his first priority doesn't met (eg. he is 31st in the list, but there are only 30 places available) then the next priority must be as his wish.

An example:

```
ID  | Name   | Tenis   | Swiming  |  Basketball | Runing     | Score|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |John    |0        |1         |2            |3           |80    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |Bill    |1        |2         |3            |4           |65    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |Arnold  |0        |1         |0            |2           |70    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Every disciple has its maximum participients. For an example:

```
$max_tenis = 5; 

$max_swiming = 8;

$max_basketball = 10;

$max_runing = 9;
```

I qould like to select all applications for each sports and checking if they are met with the limitation set.

So that if I'm selecting all basketballs I must select all other applications with priorities more than the first priority (or second, third...) if the last priority do not met limitation.

Comment: Not able to understand what you want.. needs clarification

Comment: As above. Plus all ids are '1'. Is that correct?

Comment: No, certenly no! I forgot to edit IDs. IDs should be auto increment

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your request but I'm guessing you want to give priority to people with the highest score.

To approach this I doubt its possible to do it all in SQL, I would approach this via a php script.  I am also assuming that this script doesn't have to be super optimized as it is will not be run that often.

So my suggestion is add a field called assigned to the table above.

I would then declare all the sports as a array and assign the max values

```
$sport_slots = array("running" => 9, "basketball" => 10);
```

I would then do a count on the table and do a while loop off that count so we know we are going to work with all the people.

Then I would select the people with the highest score.

```
select * from `people` where `score`=(select max(`score`) from people) AND assigned=0;
```

with those results...determine which item they choose which sport them way to be in...make sure it has a slot in the sport_slots array (!= 0). If it does, subtract one from the sports entry and update the entry to be assigned=1.

If you need help with specific parts of this code please reply.

Comment: Could you please contact me by email rikitons@rikitons.id.lv     About part of the PHP code